# Track Flash Based Course Percentage

Tags: scorm1.2

I'm developing Flash module with AS3 now. I need to package it with SCORM 1.2.

I want to track percentage of the user when accessing my flash module. My flash module consist of single file that loads swfs. Let's say I should loads 10 swfs. When the user load 1-5, i hope it tracked as 50%.

Is it possible to do with SCORM 1.2?

I'm fairly familiar with flash but new to SCORM. I've stumble upon the Philip Hutchison's tutorials and several SCORM 1.2 document for from ADL for several days. So far haven't manage a success.

Comment: If you can tie that into the bookmark i.e. 'cmi.core.lesson_location' (255) you could theoretically convey progress simply.

Answer (score 1):

Since SO doesn't allow someone with as little rep as I to comment and ask for clarification, I'm going to have to go by assumption for some of this. The short answer is no. However, it depends what you plan to do with that progress percentage in the end.

If it is to be used in some sort of report or display within an LMS, you'll need to use an official element for just such a thing, and hope your LMS can use it. Unfortunately, SCORM 1.2 won't cut it for you there. In SCORM 2004, however, you can utilize the "cmi.progress_measure" element. See section 4.2.18 in the SCORM 2004 4th Edition RTE specification. Note: It is common to see completion percentage in an LMS related to multi-SCO packages, where the percentage of completed SCO's within a package is displayed - especially in the case of SCORM 1.2.

If the requirement is to simply store the current slide number or total number of slides viewed for the sole purpose of having this percentage value available to the SCO itself, you can simply store and retrieve this value using the "cmi.suspend_data" element in either 1.2 or 2004.

Now, using Flash's ExternalInterface to communicate between Flash and Javascript is a different question entirely. And so is how to utilize the SCORM API once you have the rest in place. Again, I cannot comment to request clarification, so I cannot say for certain what the question is exactly.